# Displaying all the items in an array using jquery and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to get all the items in an array to show using json and jquery from the song of ice and fire api. I can only get one item to show from each of the arrays.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/frederickalcantara/pen/aWeXOz

```
var data;

$.getJSON(characters[i], function(json) {
    data = json;

    var alliance = $('#alliance');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.allegiances.length; i++) {
        if (i === data.allegiances.length - 1) {
            $.getJSON(data.allegiances[i], function(json1) {
               alliance.html(json1.name);
            });
        } else {
            $.getJSON(data.allegiances[i], function(json1) {
               alliance.html(json1.name + ', ');
            });
        }

    }

    const title = $('#title');

    if (data.titles.length === "") {
        return 'N/A';
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < data.titles.length; i++) {

            if (i === data.titles.length - 1) {
                title.html(data.titles[i]);
            } else {
                title.html(data.titles[i]) + ', ';
            }

        }


    const tv = $('#seasons');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.tvSeries.length; i++) {
        if (i === data.tvSeries.length - 1) {
            tv.html(data.tvSeries[i]);
        } else {
            tv.html(data.tvSeries[i] + ', ');
        }
    }

    const actor = $('#actors')
    if (json.playedBy === "") {
        return 'N/A';
    } else {
        actor.html(json.playedBy);
    }

});
```

Comment: It looks like `.html` should be `.append`

Comment: For which array though? Also, doesn't .append require that you attach an html element to it? I'm not trying to create any html elements, I already did my html on the html page lol.

Comment: In every `for` loop that contains `.html`.

Comment: `.append` will only create an HTML element if you pass HTML to it. Plain text is appended without creating an HTML element. (As a side note, if you didn't want to be appending HTML, you probably should have been using `.text`, but that's not actually what you need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your loop. You keep replacing the value in the html element until the last value in the array. You can simplify this code like this:

```
  title.html(data.titles.join(','));
```

which replaces all of this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.titles.length; i++) {

        if (i === data.titles.length - 1) {
            title.html(data.titles[i]);
        } else {
            title.html(data.titles[i]) + ', ';
        }

    }
```

Update: Handling the allegiances.
Using a Promise here is important because you are making a number of AJAX calls and you need to be sure that they are resolved before attempting to display them. You can replace the entire for loop for the allegiances like this:

```
  Promise.all(data.allegiances.map(function(ally){
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         $.getJSON(ally, function(json) {
               resolve(json.name);
         });
     });
   }))
   .then(function(allies){
     alliance.html(allies.join(', '));
   });
```

Comment: I use the conditional, because the last point in the array will include the comma which is something I don't want.

Comment: And the `join()` takes care of that. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=control)

Comment: Ok, and what about the allegiance array? Since it uses json to get the name is there anything special I have to do or can I still use join() normally?

Comment: For that you may want to consider the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) function. Also as you are making AJAX calls in that loop you may need to consider Promises to ensure that they all complete before moving on.